# how to rollback to previous version after the updates be pushed to gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I staged and committed three files, and then I pushed it to gerrit for review, but one of the file need to rollback to the previous version which is before the updates, how to roll it back?

Answer (score 0):

git checkout HEAD~

git commit

latest squash both commits using git rebase --interactive

OR

git reset HEAD~

commit - #Ensure that you keep the same changeID.

Comment: The first one edits commits that are already pushed. The second one would work, and may be even better than mine due to the changeID. However, it still edits pushed commits.

Comment: I only want to rollback one of the files, not all of them, in the second one, will it rollback all the files?

Answer (score 0):

If you would not have pushed, you would use `git rebase --interactive` for that. You would simply edit the commit you made and include the old version of the file instead of the new one.

However, you have already pushed. The rebase would rewrite the history, and other developers may have done work based on your commit. Therefore, you can't rebase safely.

Instead, you need to create a new commit that changes the file back to the old one.
To do this, type:

```
git checkout <the commit with the correct file> <the file>
git add <the file>
git commit
```

The first command replaces the file with the older (correct) one. After that, you simply commit. Then, you can push the new commit into gerrit.

Of course, the wrong file will still be available in gerrit and git (by checking out the wrong commit) but you can't stop that from happening. You have already pushed.

Comment: while, the files are pushed to gerrit, but it is not merged to the branch, I mean, I did not submit and publish the updates.

Comment: In this case, go with forvaidya's second answer.